# Can we use prometheus and node_exporter on different machines

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

Can we use prometheus on one machine and node_exporter on different nodes and get all of the metrics collected to single machine where prometheus is present?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The idea is that you have one (or a few) Prometheus servers, which collect metrics from as many other servers as you want.

You do not have to run Prometheus itself on every server you want to monitor -- just the exporter(s) that you want to collect metrics from (for example, node_exporter).

Answer (score 1):

That is prometheus designed for.
Install prometheus server on one machine and install node_exporter everywhere.